# Python multiprocessing: Permission denied

Tags: python, linux

I'm getting an error when trying to execute python program that uses multiprocessing package:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 178, in RLock
    return RLock()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 142, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, RECURSIVE_MUTEX, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

It looks like the user doesn't have permission to access shared memory. When executing with root privileges it works fine.

Is there any solution to run it as normal user(not root)?

Python version 2.6.2 , OS is Linux 2.6.18 (CentOS release 5.4) and it's VPS machine.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For POSIX semaphores to work, the users need r/w access to shared memory (`/dev/shm`).

Check the permissions to `/dev/shm`. On my laptop (Ubuntu) it looks like this:

```
$ ls -ld /dev/shm
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root          40 2010-01-05 20:34 shm
```

To permanently set the correct permissions (even after a reboot), add the following to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
```

Haven't tried this, just copied from a [forum post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/permission-denied-error-creating-posix-semaphores-487624/).

Comment: Using `none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0` in `/etc/fstab` still works but is more secure. See e.g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=664457

Comment: I was getting the same error when I tried to run Minecraft-Overviewer on Fedora 14. This question and @Day's comment were a great help!

Comment: @Day's comment resolved OSError: [Error 38] Function not implemented for me when trying to get celery working with django on an Ubuntu 10.10 VPS

Comment: @sherpya Thanks, I didn't know the ``-d`` flag. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Under CentOS 7.3.1611, permissions on /dev/shm of `drwxr-xr-t. 2 root root` were causing Ansible running as nonroot to fail with `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.  Running `chmod go+w /dev/shm` remediated this Ansible error.  I found that these errors weren't related to mount status (reported `rw`).  Instead they are related to directory permissions on `/dev/shm` mount point.  The only permanent remedy I've found so far is to add this to /etc/rc.local (and be sure to `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`):

`/usr/bin/chmod go+w /dev/shm`

Comment: I'm having trouble on Ubuntu 18.04, file permissions look okay, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040724/how-to-fix-repo-forall-command-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Just checking by in 2022 to say that this post from 2010, referencing a forum post from 2006, that itself references a solution from 1997(!) has saved my day. This should be in a museum or something.. :D

Comment: Also for 2023!  Thanks!

Comment: Just added this fix to mine so uvicorn would run under python3.  Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In my OVH VPS Classic, this error was caused by a loop in /dev/shm and /run/shm.
Both were symlinks linking to each other.
So as root here is what I did:

```
# rm /dev/shm
# mkdir /dev/shm
# chmod 777 /dev/shm
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Then I modified the shm line from:

```
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw 0 0
```

To:

```
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
```

Restarted the server... And that fixed the problem!
Alternatively you can mount shm manually:

```
# mount /dev/shm
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me while other solutions didn't. Only difference was that I had to use sudo.

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution without rebooting is

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/shm
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: This introduces a severe safety issue, as chmod 777 makes /dev/shm accessible and writable to everyone. I would avoid this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the recommendations related to chmod and shm, but in my case the solution was:

##### Using conda navigator:

- In base-environment run (in order to see the navigator):

  ```
  $ anaconda-navigator
  ```
- Create a new conda environment: from the button CREATE in the navigator
- Select the new environment with your mouse
- Install "notebook": Install it from anaconda-navigator in the new environment

##### Using command line:

- Create a new anaconda enviroment (enviroment name "my_new_env"):

  ```
  $ conda create --name my_new_env
  ```
- Enter to my_new_env:

  ```
  $ conda activate my_new_env
  ```
- Install Jupyter notebook:

  ```
  $ conda install jupyter-core (OR $ conda install notebook)
  ```

As a summary, don't use snap to install Jupyter notebook.

Comment: 这个回答，用中文俗语，叫 `牛头不对马嘴`  这显然是权限问题