# Django Celery implementation - OSError : [Errno 38] Function not implemented

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I installed django-celery and I tried to start up the worker server but I get an OSError that a function isn't implemented.  I'm running CentOS release 5.4 (Final) on a VPS:

```
    . broker -> amqp://guest@localhost:5672/
    . queues ->
        . celery -> exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery
    . concurrency -> 4
    . loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
    . logfile -> [stderr]@WARNING
    . events -> OFF
    . beat -> OFF
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,364: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,364: WARNING/MainProcess] File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,364: WARNING/MainProcess] execute_manager(settings)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,364: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,364: WARNING/MainProcess] utility.execute()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,364: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,365: WARNING/MainProcess] self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,365: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,365: WARNING/MainProcess] self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,365: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 218, in execute
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,365: WARNING/MainProcess] output = self.handle(*args, **options)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,365: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_celery-2.0.0-py2.6.egg/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py", line 22, in handle
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,366: WARNING/MainProcess] run_worker(**options)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,366: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 385, in run_worker
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,366: WARNING/MainProcess] return Worker(**options).run()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,366: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 218, in run
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,366: WARNING/MainProcess] self.run_worker()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,366: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 312, in run_worker
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,367: WARNING/MainProcess] worker.start()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,367: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 206, in start
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,367: WARNING/MainProcess] component.start()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,367: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/concurrency/processes/__init__.py", line 54, in start
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,367: WARNING/MainProcess] maxtasksperchild=self.maxtasksperchild)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,367: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 448, in __init__
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,368: WARNING/MainProcess] self._setup_queues()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,368: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 564, in _setup_queues
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,368: WARNING/MainProcess] self._inqueue = SimpleQueue()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,368: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 315, in __init__
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,368: WARNING/MainProcess] self._rlock = Lock()
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,368: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 117, in __init__
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,369: WARNING/MainProcess] SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,369: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,369: WARNING/MainProcess] sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,369: WARNING/MainProcess] OSError
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,369: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2010-07-22 17:10:01,369: WARNING/MainProcess] [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Am I just totally screwed or is there an easy way to resolve this?

Comment: This answer to another question seems to show that multiprocessing is at least working on CentOS 5.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied

So you're probably not that far from solving it.

Answer (score 13):

same issue on ubuntu 10, even after full rights on shmem are given - problem still here...

UP- finally done, /dev/shm was not mounted. so 
add shm to fstab
mount shm
set full 777 permissions  on /dev/shm

Comment: I've got exactly this problem, /dev/shm was there but not 777 so I chmodded it, but after the problem still exists (Ubuntu 10.10 VPS). Any idea how to fix it (I don't even know what the problem is really)?

Comment: Got it working by adding `none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0` to `/etc/fstab` and rebooting, got this info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied#comment-6467139

Comment: Why rebooting? Isn't "mount -a" enough?