# OSError 38 [Errno 38] with multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I'm having the following error:

```
$ sudo chmod a+rwxt /dev/shm/
$ ls -ld /dev/shm/
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Feb  4 06:56 /dev/shm/
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> mp = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 227, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 84, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 131, in _setup_queues
    self._inqueue = SimpleQueue()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 328, in __init__
    self._rlock = Lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 117, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

What else could be the reason for this error (apart from read/write access to /dev/shm)?

Thanks!

Comment: did you compile this python from source?

Comment: Did you check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314031/django-celery-implementation-oserror-errno-38-function-not-implemented

Comment: it seems that this is a debian amd64 and ppc specific bug...

Comment: @Bobby this is not what you think. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314031/django-celery-implementation-oserror-errno-38-function-not-implemented

Comment: @xyz-123 Not really, I'm experiencing it on an arm9 system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/enumarate-through-dictionary-with-python-2-6/21069676?noredirect=1#21069676

Answer (score 20):

For anyone else coming here from Google, the answer is at [Django Celery Implementation - OSError errno 38 - Function not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314031/django-celery-implementation-oserror-errno-38-function-not-implemented#comment7543003_3699231):

> Got it working by adding `none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0
>   0` to `/etc/fstab` and rebooting

Instead of rebooting, `sudo mount /dev/shm` works.

Comment: I can't do sudo. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 7):

I suspect this have to do something with this:
http://bugs.python.org/issue3770

From the Python docs:

> **Warning**: Some of this package’s functionality requires a functioning shared semaphore implementation on the host operating system. Without one, the `multiprocessing.synchronize` module will be disabled, and attempts to import it will result in an ImportError. See issue 3770 for additional information.

This may or may not be related, since it talks about `multiprocessing.synchronize`, but from what I understand, some implementations on some platforms just don't implement the semaphore API python relies upon here, which might be your problem.

Comment: but this would lead to an ImportError rather than the OSError?

Comment: it may not be an import error as there are other pieces of the module which may be of use

Comment: @ahojnnes: I'm not quite sure. Looking at the C source code, there are several places from which an OSError may be thrown. Whether or not they're thrown, but they seem to be based on the OS error value (e.g. errno or GetLastError()).