# Node.js compile error on Linux

Tags: linux, python, compilation, node.js, synology

I'm currently running a heavily modified Synology DSM (x86 bromolow based) on my server (bootstrapped, etc.), and for some services, I would need node.js.

And thus, I've been following the tutorials, more or less. Installed the required packages (python2.7, make, gcc, etcetera), grabbed the source, checked out the latest stable, and tried to compile.

But I ran into a slight issue while trying to run configure. Here's the output log: http://pastebin.com/BPXX4XiY

Then tried with Python2.6 too: http://pastebin.com/Xg4qHspG

Problem is, Error 38 and "Function not implemented" does not give a slightest hint on what might be missing - there is simply no reference to it.

Did anyone else have this problem, and if yes, how did you solve it?

**EDIT**

Using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033599/oserror-38-errno-38-with-multiprocessing), it still does not work. /dev/shm/ (after manually creating the node, and mounting it) is there, with 0777 access rights, and yet Python still returns the same error.

Comment: check this out, seems similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033599/oserror-38-errno-38-with-multiprocessing

Comment: While it is indeed similar (the reason is the same), the solution won't work, as this modified Linux has no /dev/shm node by default. Adding the line to fstab and mounting it results in the following:

mount: mounting none on /dev/shm failed: No such file or directory