# Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x, python-2.6, dictionary-comprehension

How can I make the following functionality compatible with versions of Python earlier than Python 2.7?

```
gwfuncs = [reboot, flush_macs, flush_cache, new_gw, revert_gw, send_log]      
gw_func_dict = {chr(2**i): func for i, func in enumerate(gwfuncs[:8])}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use:

```
gw_func_dict = dict((chr(2**i), func) for i, func in enumerate(gwfuncs[:8]))
```

That's the `dict()` function with a generator expression producing `(key, value)` pairs.

Or, to put it generically, a dict comprehension of the form:

```
{key_expr: value_expr for targets in iterable <additional loops or if expressions>}
```

can always be made compatible with Python < 2.7 by using:

```
dict((key_expr, value_expr) for targets in iterable <additional loops or if expressions>)
```

Comment: I guess the second one is compatible with both Python<2.7 and Python>=2.7? If not I would usually use try to get a robust version for both but I don't think I can catch the Syntax Error.

Comment: @Kvothe the syntax in this answer is forward-compatible and works on Python 2.4 and newer (including all Python 3.x releases).