# Syntax Error in for loop Python

Tags: python

this runs fine on my local machine, but as soon as I deploy it the service fails saying invalid syntax "for"

```
  data = {k: request.form[k] for k in request.form.iterkeys()}   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Appreciate the help on this, it's been a very long time since I did anything with Python and this one has got me stumped.

Comment: what versions of Python are you running locally and for the service?

Comment: upgrade to python 2.7

Comment: The syntax requires Python 2.7 or newer. Does your server run 2.6 perhaps?

Comment: Also see [Dict comprehension with Python 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21069668)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this is probably a version issue. Try:

```
data = dict((k,request.form[k]) for k in request.form.iterkeys())
```

Answer (score 1):

The python version on your local machine might be different from the version you have on the server.

Comment: I will check that now.

Comment: ah yes, i'm running 2.7 server is running 2.6 - Will see if I can't get that changed. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehensions are a relatively new addition to 2.x. Convert it to a genex that generates (key, value) pairs and pass it to the `dict()` constructor.

Comment: Could provide an example. Not trying to be cheeky, just not familiar with Python.

Comment: @SimonH: I linked you to a post with an example in the comments on your question.