# What does "masterlist = [row for row in c2]" syntax mean where masterlist and c2 are variable names

Tags: python, python-2.7

This refers to the solution stated in [Python: Comparing two CSV files and searching for similar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268929/python-comparing-two-csv-files-and-searching-for-similar-items)

I want to know what does syntax

```
masterlist = [row for row in c2]
```

mean in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, list comprehensions are a quick way to map one list to another with a transforming expression. It's like calling map() but with syntactic sugar.

e.g.

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #or range(1, 6)
squares = [x*x for x in list_]
print squares
#[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: It's not like calling `map`, because you can't give an expression to map, only a function.  Using your example, `map(x*x, list_)` is a syntax error.  Further, on python3 `map` returns a *map object* as opposed to a list.  Last, `map` is typically slower than a list comprehension (typical exception is when the function given to map is a python builtin).  A better way to think of it might be an inline for loop.

Comment: actually isn't the same but the difference in map is that instead of x*x you write `lambda x: x*x` but it's practically the same - particularly when you have to explain the concept.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but in this particular case a useless one. It's more efficient to just do:

```
masterlist = list(c2)
```

as that would *also* copy all elements from the `c2` iterable into a new list object.

A list comprehension would normally be used to filter or transform elements from an iterable; say to pick only certain rows, or only a specific column from each row:

```
masterlist = [row[1] for row in c2]
```

would pick out just the one column the referenced answer actually uses in their code.

The accepted answer there is missing out on several Python idioms and best practices and operates in quadratic time (duration to process is a function of the size of `hosts.csv` times the size of `masterlist.csv`); it should be rewritten to:

```
import csv

with open('hosts.csv', 'rb') as hosts, open('masterlist.csv', 'rb') as master:
    with open('results.csv', 'wb') as results:    
        reader = csv.reader(hosts)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        master_indices = {r[1]: i for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master), 1)}

        for row in reader:
            index = master_indices.get(row[3])
            if index is not None:
                message = 'FOUND in master list (row {})'.format(index)
            else:
                message = 'NOT FOUND in master list'
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Here I replaced the list comprehension with a dictionary comprehension instead; creating a dictionary mapping the second column of each CSV row to a row number (produced with `enumerate()`); now the code to test if `row[3]` from the `hosts.csv` file is present in that column is reduced to just a `dict.get()` call, mapping directly to the row number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the revised solution. Greatly appreciate it. I gave another solution an up vote because I just wanted to know the meaning of that one expression.

Comment: Sure and not a problem; I got disconnected briefly and didn't get a chance to further elaborate. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the List Comprehension link. Things are much clearer now. I wish I could give both the solutions the up-vote :)

Comment: +1 since I learned what the hell is a dictionary comprehension with your answer xD. BTW in which Python version is supported? it is in EVERY 2.7.x version?

Comment: 2.7 and up, and in python 3. See [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21069668) for what to do before 2.7.