# Why does this python code work in the pyspark but not in spark-submit?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark

I'm fairly inexperienced with python, and I'm having trouble getting some code running.

```
counts = {key:len(list(group)) for key, group in it.groupby(sorted(topics))}
```

That line will run in `pyspark` (interactive mode) but if I attempt to `spark-submit` it I get a `SyntaxError` exception.  The following code is equivalent and does run in both cases:

```
counts = {}
for key, group in it.groupby(sorted(topics)):
    counts[key] = len(list(group))
```

Can anyone tell me why the first code doesn't work in spark-submit.  If it makes a difference, the code is being executed within a function 1 tab out.

The exception I get using a dictionary comprehension:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sessions.py", line 24, in <module>
    execfile("./sessionSearch.py")
  File "./sessionSearch.py", line 50
    counts = {poop:len(list(group)) for poop, group in it.groupby(sorted(topics))}
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please specify the specific syntax error that you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cluster runs Python 2.6, which doesn't support dictionary comprehension syntax.

Either use a generator expression plus the `dict()` function (see [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7)), or [configure your cluster to deploy Python 2.7](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220082).

Using `dict()` your line would be:

```
counts = dict((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in it.groupby(sorted(topics)))
```