# I'm having troubles with Uber Python API

Tags: python, api, import, uber-api

I'm coding in python, using version 2.6, working with the Uber API, and when I try to import the library `uber_rides.auth` it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\underdevelopment.biz\httpdocs\web\webtemp3\uber\socket.py", line 4, in <module>    
    from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant
  File "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\underdevelopment.biz\httpdocs\web\webtemp3\uber\uber_rides\auth.py", line 133
    query_params = [qp: query_params[qp][0] for qp in query_params]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The original code of my script is this:

```
print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant
def main():
    auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
        'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx',
        'xxxxx-xxxxx',
        'xxx-xxxxxxxxx',
        '',
    )
    auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It seems the error is from the library but I can't find it yet.

Comment: Yes, the error is in the library. They used invalid syntax. It may be they meant to use a dict comprehension instead.

Comment: Where did you get the files from? Looking at [the GitHub source](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/blob/master/uber_rides/auth.py#L133) the syntax is correct there. It also was never wrong, that's the initial commit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's invalid Python syntax. However, it is not clear how you ended up with that file.

Someone or something altered that file. That's not the [original source code as distributed by Uber](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/blob/master/uber_rides/auth.py#L133), where that line uses the correct syntax for a dictionary comprehension:

```
query_params = {qp: query_params[qp][0] for qp in query_params}
```

Re-install the project, the error is not there upstream.

Note that the above syntax is only available in Python 2.7 and up. You could try to replace it with a `dict()` call with a generator expression, see [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7/21069676#21069676):

```
query_params = dict((qp, query_params[qp][0]) for qp in query_params)
```

Take into account that there may be *other* issues with the code, upgrading to Python 2.7 is probably the better option.

Comment: I changed the code but Throws an error again:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\underdevelopment.biz\httpdocs\web\webtemp3\uber\socket.py", line 4, in <module>
    from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant
  File "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\underdevelopment.biz\httpdocs\web\webtemp3\uber\uber_rides\auth.py", line 133
    query_params = {qp: query_params[qp][0] for qp in query_params}

                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ArturoVasquez: You are using Python 2.6. The library requires Python 2.7 or newer.