# Convert Python 2.7 code to Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code which works fine in 2.7 but fails in 2.6

```
def recursively_prune_dict_keys(obj, keep):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: recursively_prune_dict_keys(v, keep) for k, v in obj.items() if k in keep}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [recursively_prune_dict_keys(item, keep) for item in obj]
    else:
        return obj
```

I get invalid syntax error for line below:

```
return {k: recursively_prune_dict_keys(v, keep) for k, v in obj.items() if k in keep}
```

Any idea what needs to change to make it work in 2.6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the *dictionary comprehension* (which is not supported in Python 2.6 and below) with a list comprehension wrapped by a call to [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
return dict([(k, recursively_prune_dict_keys(v, keep))
             for k, v in obj.items() if k in keep])
```

Comment: The point of note is that the code uses a `dict comprehension` which were introduced in python 2.7. Simply constructing a dictionary by hand as done here, is the fix. Here's the relevant [PEP 274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)