# Python Dictionary comprehension for a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from the following list

```
[{'fips': '01001', 'state': 'AL', 'name': 'Autauga County'}, {'fips': '20005', 'state': 'KS', 'name': 'Atchison County'}, {'fips': '47145', 'state': 'TN', 'name': 'Roane County'}]
```

The result should have the name as the key and 'United States' as the value.

eg:

```
{'Autauga County': 'United States', 'Atchison County' : 'United States',  'Roane County' : 'United States'}
```

I can do this with a couple of for loops but i want to learn how to do it using Dictionary Comprehensions.

Comment: You might want to specify which Python version you are using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
in_list = [{'fips': '01001', 'state': 'AL', 'name': 'Autauga County'}, 
           {'fips': '20005', 'state': 'KS', 'name': 'Atchison County'},
           {'fips': '47145', 'state': 'TN', 'name': 'Roane County'}]

out_dict = {x['name']: 'United States' for x in in_list if 'name' in x}
```

Some notes for learning:

- Comprehensions are only for Python 2.7 onwards
- Dictionary comprehensions are very similar to list comprehensions except with curly braces `{}` (and keys)
- In case you didn't know, you can also add more complicated control-flow after the for loop in a comprehension such as `[x for x in some_list if (cond)]`

For completeness, if you can't use comprehensions, try this

```
out_dict = {}

for dict_item in in_list:
    if not isinstance(dict_item, dict):
        continue

    if 'name' in dict_item:
        in_name = dict_item['name']
        out_dict[in_name] = 'United States'
```

As mentioned in the comments, for Python 2.6 you can replace the `{k: v for k,v in iterator}` with:

```
dict((k,v) for k,v in iterator)
```

You can read more about this [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Oh my bad - so used to Python 3. I must say though, pretty new here and that's the fastest set of downvotes I've gotten - is it because of the lack of Python 2 support or is there something else?

Comment: @tehjoker yes, well, dictionary comprehensions only work for python 2.7+ so it's sort of a moot point...

Comment: Understood haha (it was really fast though), thought I did something terribly wrong. Will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I'm completely puzzled why you got downvotes. Don't feel bad for writing a Python 2.7 or 3 answer, without a version number in the question Python 3 is a good assumption.

Comment: I am puzzled too. I think it is safe to assume that when the question asks about dictionary comprehensions that we are talking about a Python version that supports dictionary comprehensions...

Comment: Haha thanks guys - I'm not particularly fussed with rep, I think answering questions is a great way to learn coding - and downvotes just make sure you produce the best code! On a side note, someone should give an answer with both Python 2.x and 3.x support, I look forward to it (haven't done Python 2 for a while)

Comment: Seems like it's a valid solution, I took the pitch fork out too quick once I seen the Error on my screen! I've changed my vote and began downloading Python 2.7+.....happy coding!

Comment: @K.J.Phan 2.6 support is quite simple, you can replace `{k: v for k,v in iterator}` with `dict((k, v) for k,v in iterator)`. Basically just passing a iterator over tuples to the dictionary constructor,,

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little solution working for both python2.7.x and python 3.x:

```
data = [
    {'fips': '01001', 'state': 'AL', 'name': 'Autauga County'},
    {'fips': '20005', 'state': 'KS', 'name': 'Atchison County'},
    {'fips': '47145', 'state': 'TN', 'name': 'Roane County'},
    {'fips': 'xxx', 'state': 'yyy'}
]

output = {item['name']: 'United States' for item in data if 'name' in item}
print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

The loop/generator version is:

```
location_list = [{'fips': '01001', 'state': 'AL', 'name': 'Autauga County'},
        {'fips': '20005', 'state': 'KS', 'name': 'Atchison County'},
        {'fips': '47145', 'state': 'TN', 'name': 'Roane County'}]
location_dict = {location['name']:'United States' for location in location_list}
```

Output:

```
{'Autauga County': 'United States', 'Roane County': 'United States',
 'Atchison County': 'United States'}
```

If you search on Stackoverflow for dictionary comprehension, solutions using the `{ }` generator expression start to show up: [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: `dict` and `list` are poor names to use as they shadow the built-ins.

Answer (score -2):

That should do the trick for you

```
states_dict = [{'fips': '01001', 'state': 'AL', 'name': 'Autauga County'}, {'fips': '20005', 'state': 'KS', 'name': 'Atchison County'}, {'fips': '47145', 'state': 'TN', 'name': 'Roane County'}]

{states_dict[i]['name']:'United States' for i, elem in enumerate(states_dict)}
```

Comment: Just to get better understanding, any issues with that ?. I believe it works fine and I tested it

Comment: @BlackHawk It's a confusing and inelegant way to accomplish something that can be done much simpler (see top-rated answers).

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry my dump answer. I'm still learning and was trying to help only.