# How to write this from python 2.6

Tags: python

I have wrote a code in python 2.7, but im not sure how to write it in python 2.6, bcz its give some error when it run on 2.6

```
a = {0:1234}
b = {0:1500}
c = {key: b[key] - a.get(key, 0) for key in a.keys()}
d = {x:y for x,y in c.items() if y!=0}
print d
```

Error

> ./run.py -e dev -s atlas   File "./run.py", line 59
>       Lz_ofstes_subtract = {key: lz_offset_2[key] - lz_offset_1.get(key, 0) for key in lz_offset_1.keys()}
>                                                                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Whats the error. Show us.

Comment: Edited with Error

Comment: Line 3 and line 4's dictionary comprehensions (the ones that set `c` and `d`) are probably what's causing you the problem - dictionary comprehensions were added in python 2.7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7 will answer what you need to do in 2.6 and before.

Comment: Thanks it is working as per your reference.