# invalid syntax error in list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to execute below code but it's throwing some error, whereas same code is running on jupyter notebook. I am not sure what's going wrong. The python version is 2 on both platform. This codes takes json file as input, pick 'Data' key and place all values under it into csv file.

***command line :***

Python version : 2.6.6

```
$ python Parser.py /data/csdb/stage/fundapiresponse.json /data/csp53/csdb/stage/fundresponse.csv
  File "Parser.py", line 27
    flat_data = [{k:v for j in i for k, v in j.items()} for i in zip(*[element['Data'] for key in element])]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

***Code:***

```
#################################################
# importing libraries
#################################################
import csv
import json
import collections
import sys

#################################################
# Reading input and output file from command line
#################################################

infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]

print infile
print outfile

#################################################
# Read JSON and build CSV layout
#################################################
with open(infile,'r') as f:
    data= json.load(f)

with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    for element in data: 
        flat_data = [{k:v for j in i for k, v in j.items()} for i in zip(*[element['Data'] for key in element])]
        csvwriter = DictWriter(f,flat_data[0].keys(),lineterminator='\n')
        csvwriter.writerows(flat_data)
```

*Jupyter notebook :*

Python 2

```
#################################################
# importing libraries
#################################################
import csv
import json
import collections
import sys

#################################################
# Reading input and output file from command line
#################################################

infile = 'fundapiresponse.json'
outfile = 'fundresponse.csv'

print infile
print outfile

#################################################
# Read JSON and build CSV layout
#################################################
with open(infile,'r') as f:
    data= json.load(f)

with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    for element in data: 
        flat_data = [{k:v for j in i for k, v in j.items()} for i in zip(*[element['Data'] for key in element])]
        csvwriter = DictWriter(f,flat_data[0].keys(),lineterminator='\n')
        csvwriter.writerows(flat_data)
```

Comment: There's no syntax error in python 2.7, but I'm not sure about 2.6.6...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dict comprehensions (PEP274)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) with curly brackets and colon notation were only introduced in Python2.7. Before that, you had to use the `dict` constructor with an appropriate list or generator of pairs:

```
dict((k, v) for j in i for k, v in j.iteritems())  # items works, too
```

See also [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7).