# How to configure alternative to `/dev/shm/` or `_multiprocessing.SemLock` in Python

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing, shared-memory, hypervisor

**Query** : Is there any way in Python to say:

- Don't use `/dev/shm` for shared memory storage and use some other temporary location such as `/tmp` instead. **OR**
- Instead of `multiprocessing.SemLock` use `threading.Lock` for synchronization (if it's feasible and not illogical).

**Background**:

I am running a simple `multiprocessing.Pool` example on an ESX (hypervisor) which is running into [OSError : Function not implemented error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033599/oserror-38-errno-38-with-multiprocessing).

Other mentions to this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033599/oserror-38-errno-38-with-multiprocessing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005930/multiprocessing-semlock-is-not-implemented-when-running-on-aws-lambda)) on StackOverflow have pointed out that it happens when `/dev/shm` is not mounted. Due to which, `_multiprocessing.SemLock`fails to create synchronization lock(s).

It is actually the case for me as `ls -lrt /dev/shm` fails for me. However I cannot try the solutions recommended on the above links as

- `mount` as mount command is not implemented on the platform (ESX/VMKernel) I am running on.
- VM is not persistent and `/etc/fstab` gets washed away on shutdown itself.

So I am looking for ways to either use threading.Lock() for synchronization or ask Python to not to use `/dev/shm/` for synchronization.

Comment: I understand like 80% of your question. Where I'm stumbling is that you try to use both threading (`threading.lock`) and `multiprocessing`. Are you still unsure which one to choose? Or did you mix up the two? Because you cannot use `threading.lock` using processes

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I have the same issue on AWS Lambda, where /dev/shm isn't mounted in the container the lambda is run in.

Answer (score 2):

If you try using a `threading.Lock` object in two `multiprocessing` process, the two `Lock` objects won't be linked. The `threading.Lock` relies on the fact that 2 `Thread` will run on the same core and share the file descriptors and GIL. This is not the case with 2 `Process`.

The module `_multiprocessing.semaphore` relies on the OS `pthread.sem_open` to create the `SemLock` object. This means that the main question is: Is there some OS semaphores implemented on ESX? If there is, you can implement your own `SemLock` objects using `ctypes` and inspiration from [loky.backend.semlock](https://github.com/tomMoral/loky/blob/master/loky/backend/semlock.py), which allows you to accesses the internal `pthread` primitives.

Note that it may require lot of work to make sure SemLock is correctly used with the `multiprocessing` module. A solution could be to use a modify version of `loky`, that use this `SemLock` if you succeed in implementing it on ESX.