# Docker on Google Cloud Run - Python Multiprocessing: OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, google-cloud-run

I'm running a simple python web scraping script within a docker container on Cloud Run, it is invoked from the Cloud Scheduler and gives an error:

```py
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__ sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock( OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Even though I am running this in docker is there something disabled on Cloud Run that is causing this? Also would python multithreading work on Cloud Run?

I can't seem to see anything about this in the google cloud docs.

Comment: Can you share your code? And yes, multi threading is available on Cloud Run, if it run in the current request. Multi processor is also available.

Comment: This looks like an unimplemented syscall on gVisor, can you please open an issue at Cloud Run issue tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers ?

Comment: @Pentium10 looks similar but the solution there didn't work

Comment: I had this same issue when using a ThreadPool in my Cloud Run application. The answers here (even though the question asks about AWS Lambda) were helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/34005930/6410635