# Is signal library in Python safe to be used in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a timeout function inside aws lambda. On my first iteration using multiprocessing library failed because I needed a [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005930/multiprocessing-semlock-is-not-implemented-when-running-on-aws-lambda#34032458). While it seems necessary to yet implement a timeout function, I just don't want to go through the complexities of implementing it. I found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish) that describes what I need using signal library, but a comment below warned of the dangers of using signals in a multithreaded environment. I'm wondering if it's safe to use signals in aws lambda

Comment: What queue? Python  has its own queues.

Comment: queue in multiprocessing

Comment: What's wrong with python's `multiprocessing.Queue`?

Comment: I've linked an article that explains this issue better than I could.

Comment: Lambda functions should finish as quickly as possible and in fact have a limited runtime. Are you sure this is the right approach to begin with? Perhaps you should use one of the other AWS services like CloudWatch to trigger another Lamba call later.

Comment: @deceze That is a valid point. I haven't considered using a different lambda. But nonetheless, it may yet prove useful to handle a timeout when my current lambda needs a lot of time (say the maximum 15mins), and encounters an error (db unresponsive?)  that will cause it to hang indefinitely.