# How to change the permission of celeryd in django

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I have seen that when i execute `celeryd` via normal user then i get permission denied error

`/opt/python2.7/bin/celeryd`

But it executes with root user

In the text it says that

```
"Running celeryd with superuser privileges is not encouraged!")
```

How can i assign previlege to user1 for celeryd

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied regarding POSIX shared memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can add execute permissions for all users by running the following in a terminal:

`sudo chmod u+x /opt/python2.7/bin/celeryd`

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to run it? Don't all you need to do is install it via `pip install -U Celery` then import it: `from celery.task import task`? I don't think you need to 'run' it at all...

Comment: As I understand it, when you call the task (i.e. `mytask.delay(*args, **kwars)` it then sends that task to the celery daemon to perform it. So the daemon needs to be running for the task to complete.