# Semaphore with no shared memory access

Tags: python, ubuntu, multiprocessing

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied) creating semaphores in python requires read/write access to `/dev/shm`. Unfortunately, I'm working on an infrastructure in which this access is limited to read.

Is there any possible workaround?