# How should I treat joblib multiprocessing in an AWS lambda implementation?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, scikit-learn, warnings, joblib

I have a relatively simple linear regression lambda in AWS. Each instance the function is called the logs display the following:

```
/opt/python/sklearn/externals/joblib/_multiprocessing_helpers.py:38: UserWarning: [Errno 38] Function not implemented. joblib will operate in serial mode
```

```
warnings.warn('%s. joblib will operate in serial mode' % (e,))
```

I suspect this is due to sklearn running on a lambda (i.e. 'serverless') and trying to determine it's multi-processing capabilities as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied) and [this GH issue](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/391).

I am also understanding from the GH that this is not a 'fixable' issue, it will always happen when deploying with these dependencies on this hardware. I am getting back my expected results (even though I am currently maxing out the default, minimum lambda memory of 128mb).

I aim to control the warnings and would know if there is a way to either:

- stop sklearn looking for multiprocessing, so preventing the warning from issuing
- capture *this specific* warning and prevent it from being passed from my function into the cloudwatch logs
- if both are possible, which would be preferable from a aws architecture/pythonic opinion?

Answer (score 5):

None of the suggested solutions worked for me.  Digging into the source code of joblib here: https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/_multiprocessing_helpers.py, I discovered the environment variable `JOBLIB_MULTIPROCESSING` which seems to control whether joblib attempts to use multiprocessing.

Setting this to `0` solved the problem for me.

Comment: how to do it in a deployment'

Comment: What a pull, this saved me so much time! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To capture the warning and prevent it from being passed into the cloudwatch logs, you can filter the warning as follows.

```
import json
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error') 
try:
    import sklearn
except Warning:
    pass 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The [article here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/quick-dive-aws-lambda-layers-samuel-edeh), particularly towards the end, recreates and filters the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Now, we can use larger memory for AWS Lambda, up to about 10GB. I faced the same problem, and I set up 10GB of memory and then fixed it. (Actually, my program used 248MB memory.) I don't know why small memory caused the joblib problem by importing sklearn though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: aws lambda scales cpus based on how much memory you assign. So if you had a low amount of memory initially, you may have only had one cpu available. Whereas with 10GB you should get 6 cpus