# Problem while initializing the repo [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied

I have a problem. I tried initial repo (https://github.com/AOSPA/manifest -b quartz), but I can't because I have a error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wojciech/WORKSPACE/.repo/repo/main.py", line 49, in 
    import event_log
  File "/home/wojciech/WORKSPACE/.repo/repo/event_log.py", line 167, in 
    _EVENT_ID = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1)
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/**init**.py", line 253, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, **kwds)
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 108, in Value
    lock = RLock()
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/**init**.py", line 183, in RLock
    return RLock()
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 172, in **init**
    SemLock.**init**(self, RECURSIVE_MUTEX, 1, 1)
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 75, in **init**
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Thanks for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied - issue is most likely not having access to shared memory (`/dev/shm`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, most of my "permission denied" errors are resolved by running cmd as administrator. Try right click on cmd and choose "Run as administrator". If you're trying to create repo through IDE, try running it as administrator as well :)

On Linux, as you are on, add `sudo`  at the start of the command.

Comment: That's for Windows. Judging from the paths in the error messages, OP is probably on Linux. Plus the mentioned Github repo states they should be running it on Linux.

Comment: @GinoMempin Still helped me on windows, running it with `sudo` solved it, should be marked as a solution.