# UserWarning: [Errno 13] Permission denied. joblib will operate in serial mode warnings.warn('%s. joblib will operate in serial mode' % (e,))

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running a code in the Python 3 kernel in the Jupyter Notebook. My first cell looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import emcee 

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, ShuffleSplit, KFold

from scipy import stats

from math import *
import sys
import re
import os
from itertools import chain

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
```

When I run this single cell in the kernel, I get this error:

```
/home/nick/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_multiprocessing_helpers.py:45: UserWarning: [Errno 13] Permission denied.  joblib will operate in serial mode
  warnings.warn('%s.  joblib will operate in serial mode' % (e,))
```

I am pretty new to JN, so I was wondering what this error means? My code runs fine regardless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at to this thread :

[Python multiprocessing: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied)

it is said to be a permission error on linux systems for the /dev/shm  directory..